# Filter/select specific type of data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to select elements in my data array that have a specific paramter value.

ex:

```
[{type: "suv", value:10},{type: "suv", value:20},{type: "berline", value:15},{type: "berline", value:5}]
```

So, how would I only have the `type:"suv"` to be taken into account when plotting my value data?

The only similar thing I could find is selectAll, but it seems to only select elements in the UI (?)

Bear with me if this is simpler, I'm not too used to d3.js, and the information on the subject is rare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to filter your data before using `d3.selectAll(...).data(...)...`, then use this:

```
var myArr = [{type: "suv", value:10},{type: "suv", value:20},{type: "berline", value:15},{type: "berline", value:5}];
var myFilteredArr = myArr.filter(function(d) { return d.type == "suv"; });
```

Are you instead trying to modify what's already displayed?

Comment: In ES5 envionments only, but I suspect the OP wants to use d3.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array with your own filter function like this returning a new array with only the elements in it that match the filter:

```
var filterArray(arr, key, value) {
    var result = [], item;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        item = arr[i];
        if (item[key] && item[key] === value) {
            result.push(item);
        }
    }
    return(result);
}

var myArr = [{type: "suv", value:10},{type: "suv", value:20},{type: "berline", value:15},{type: "berline", value:5}];
var filteredArr = filterArray(myArr, "type", "suv");
```